# Transaction Scope in Business Logic

Tags: vb.net, data-access-layer, transactionscope, business-logic

```
Public Class BusinessLogic
    Public Sub SaveTables
    Dim daDataAccess As New DataAccess.DataAccess

        Using scope As New TransactionScope()
            daDataAccess.SaveTable1(DataSet)  
            daDataAccess.SaveTable2(DataSet)  
                   .
                   .
            daDataAccess.SaveTableN(DataSet)  
        End using
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DataAccess
    Public Sub SaveTable1(ByVal drTable As DataRow)
        'sql command
        Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("spSaveTable1")
        CMD.Connection = connect()
        CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        'add parameters in stored procedure
        CMD.Parameters.Add("Field1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = drTable("Field1")

        'execute stored procedure
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SaveTable2(ByVal drTable As DataRow)
        'sql command
        Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("spSaveTable2")
        CMD.Connection = connect()
        CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        'add parameters in stored procedure
        CMD.Parameters.Add("Field1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = drTable("Field1")

        'execute stored procedure
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub
End Class
```

A few questions:

1. Where is it ideal to define the connection in the data access class? Global to the class or for every procedure?
2. Can I use the transaction scope without passing the connection around? If I don't do this (pass the connection), regardless what I do for the first question, either the connection gets closed or I get the DTC settings error. I believe I don't need it (DTC) because I'm only accessing 1 database for all procedures in the data access component.

Please, please help. If I pass the connection around, I would have to initialize it in the business logic component which, I think, isn't good practice.

I only simplified code in order to get my point across but the business logic is very complex to say the least. It's a batch process of payroll of some sort.

What would be ideal for me would be to use the transaction scope in the business logic while leaving the connection to the data access layer.

Thank you.